# Can you use node-debug on a non-webserver application?

Tags: node.js, vagrant, text-processing, node-inspector, node-debugger

I'd like to debug an application which is basically a straightforward text-processing pipeline. After messing around with `node-debug` for a while (Vagrant port forwarding issues), all I get in the browser is output like:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 3.14.5.9
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v0.10.25
Content-Length: 0

Content-Length: 96

{"seq":0,"request_seq":1,"type":"response","command":"disconnect","success":true,"running":true}Content-Length: 553
```

There's no debug GUI.

Is it actually possible to debug a nodeJS application this way if it doesn't run a web server?

I'm starting `node-debug` like this:

```
coffee --nodejs --debug-brk toLineString.coffee
```

EDIT

Following @Brad's suggestion, I get further but it still doesn't quite work:

```
$ coffee --nodejs --debug-brk toLineString.coffee
debugger listening on port 5858
```

In another tab:
    $ node-debug
    info  - socket.io started

Now, in a browser window, I go to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

There's only boilerplate functions though, none of my code (that I can see, anyway).

If I 'run' from the debugger, my hitherto-paused process completes.

```
debugger listening on port 5858
2013-10-31 15h41m21s GPS Module 1 2110_WIMMERA HWY _F_S1_0_125140 001.gps
->2013-10-31 15h41m21s GPS Module 1 2110_WIMMERA HWY _F_S1_0_125140 001.json
2013-12-16 12h12m49s GPS Module 1 2170_HYLAND HWY _F_S1_0_59840 001.gps
->2013-12-16 12h12m49s GPS Module 1 2170_HYLAND HWY _F_S1_0_59840 001.json

=> all-lines.json
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/test$
```

The `node-debug` process is still running, and I have to kill it in order to be able to run `coffee` again. Awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can debug any Node.js application, even if it starts no server at all.  Starting node-debug starts up its own web server to handle the application.

I don't see anywhere you are actually running node-debug.  It looks like you're connecting your browser to the debugging protocol port, and not node-debug itself.  Node-debug is a web application that then connects to the debugging port of your application.

Comment: Thanks - thought I was missing something. Still a bit confused though. I install node-inspector, and start it. It tries to listen on both 8080 and 5858 - the latter of which fails, because that's the port that my debugged application is listening on? What am I missing?

Comment: @SteveBennett I don't use CoffeScript, but I think all you need to do is run `node-debug` by itself **after** starting your app with `--debug-brk`.  That works just fine for me when starting my app with Node.js directly.

Comment: If you start your app manually, don't use `node-debug` command, use `node-inspector` command [readme](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#command-line)